# Include twig 'with' html inside twig

Tags: html, twig

I have a .html.twig file inside which I want to include another html.twig file, while passing some html with the `with` keyword. The problem is that it is not rendered as HTML but plain text.
Example:

```
#base.html.twig
<div>
  Some content ...
  {% include 'AppBundle::partials/speech-bubble.html.twig' with {'text': "This is <br/> HTML content"} %}
<div>

#speech-bubble.html.twig
<div class="speechbubble-wrapper">
  <div class="speechbubble-text">
    {{ text }}
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that in the result instead of:

> This is 
>  HTML content

I see

```
This is <br/> HTML content
```

Comment: `{{ text  | raw }}` Should use `raw` filter to prevent escaping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DarkBee commented, using the raw filter on text solved the problem: `{{ text | raw }}`. Thank you!